# Google Analytics Custom event tracking / goals not working with new Google Analytics Tracking Code

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to track click event on a specific phone no. on my website with the new Google Analytic tracking code "gtag.js"

```
<a onclick="gtag('event', 'Call Check 1', {'event_category': 'Click to call','event_action':'7976904748',event_label': 'Number clicked'});" href="tel:7976904748">7976904748</a>
```

Currently i am using this code but it doesn't send anything.

I have searched a lot on internet but nothing worked for me. Please help in finding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error near event label, as there's an additional ' before the colon.

Also, please note, that as per the gtag event tracking [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events), the event action is not part of the additional details object. However, you are setting the action as 'Call Check 1', and later setting it to the phone number clicked, and this latter seems to overwrite the first one.

**EDIT**

Your code should look like this, with corrected typo

```
gtag('event', 
     'Call Check 1', 
     {
       'event_category': 'Click to call',
       'event_action':'7976904748',
       'event_label': 'Number clicked'
     });
```

However, you might want to include only one action in your call (where I have used 'Number clicked' as action, and the number as a label):

```
gtag('event', 
     'Number clicked', 
     {
       'event_category': 'Click to call',
       'event_label': '7976904748'
     });
```

Comment: Please send me the correct code as i am unable to do it right.